# Getting width/height in a slotted lit-element in Edge

Tags: css, shadow-dom, custom-element, lit-element

I've got one lit-element, `inner-element`, slotted into another lit-element, `outer-element`. For flexibility, the `outer-element` gets to set the width and height of the `inner-element` using CSS. The `inner-element` needs to know it's width and height to determine how to draw its SVG content.

How can `inner-element` reliably learn its own width and height across browsers?

I've got a live example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/7pkfkx-j9rnx9

I'm using `updated()` to get the width/height based on this very helpful information:
https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/507#issuecomment-459546838

In Chrome, the example works fine - the SVG displays "width = 150  height = 100". But in Edge, I get "width = 300 height = 303.8". Note that even in Edge, the `inner-element` ends up having the correct width and height (150x100), it just seems to be getting there after `updated()` has been called.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to Edge in order to confirm, but there are a few things you might be interested in testing here.

1) In your `index.ts` you have the following code:

```
    import './inner-element.js';
    import './outer-element.js';
```

This means that the inner element, will register and upgrade *before* the outer element has been registered and upgraded, which means that its size will be determined initially as if `outer-element` is a `div`, and then subsequently be granted the slotted styles inside of `outer-element`. Swap the imports to prevent this specific race order from occuring.

2) You are measuring in `firstUpdated()` which can *technically* happen before the element hit's the page, meaning that you are measuring an unrendered element, which is an element that has no size. Waiting until `connectedCallback()` can ensure that you are measuring the element "in page".

3) Measuring the element synchronously means you *might* be measuring before all of the parent based/classed based/etc code has been run, using `requestAnimationFrame()` in `connectedCallback()` can help ensure that you aren't measuring until you can be 100% sure that the element is ready to be measured.

Try this demo out to confirm: https://stackblitz.com/edit/measure?file=inner-element.js

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that a reliable way to get the rendered width and height of the `inner-element` is to access them in a `window.setTimeout()` callback registered in `firstUpdated()`.

This is demonstrated [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/7pkfkx-qqdamo).

Whereas the LitElement doesn't always have access to its own rendered width and height when its' `updated()` or `firstUpdated()` is called, it does seem to have access to these values when the timeout callback is called.

I would feel more comfortable marking this answer as correct if I could articulate why this is the case, but empirically it is working.

Comment: Property values could be the result of a promise?